# Unable to remove the Active sync devices leaf object from AD user

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete a user account from AD, but it fails as the user object contains some leaf objects (Exchange active sync devices).

[image: Leaf objects under the AD user]

Tried using the Exchange powershell cmdlet:

```
Remove-ActiveSyncDevice
```

but the "ExchangeActiveSyncDevices" leaf object does not get removed from the user object.

After entering the command *Remove-ActiveSyncDevice*

[image]

Is there a way to completely remove the `ExchangeActiveSyncDevices` from the user object in AD through exchange powershell?

Comment: Have a look at [Get-ActiveSyncDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/devices/get-activesyncdevice?view=exchange-ps) or [Get-MobileDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/devices/get-mobiledevice?view=exchange-ps) if you are using Exchange 2013 or later. Then loop through all devices for that user and remove them with `Remove-ActiveSyncDevice` or [Remove-MobileDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/devices/remove-mobiledevice?view=exchange-ps).

Answer (score 0):

Untested by me, but by reading the documentation, this should work:

```
# parameter Mailbox can use any of these user properties:
# Name
# Alias
# Distinguished name (DN)
# Canonical DN
# <domain name>\<account name>
# Email address
# GUID
# LegacyExchangeDN
# SamAccountName
# User ID or user principal name (UPN)

# get the list of devices for your user and loop through, removing them one-by-one
Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox "the.user@yourcompany.com" | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Remove-ActiveSyncDevice -WhatIf
}
```

Exchange 2013 or later

```
Get-MobileDevice -Mailbox "the.user@yourcompany.com" | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Remove-MobileDevice -WhatIf
}
```

When satisfied with what info is shown in the console, remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually have the code remove the devices.

Comment: Even with the Remove-ActiveSyncDevice cmdlet, the leaf objects are not fully removed. I have edited my question with relevant screenshots

Comment: @Jesvin You may need to disable ActiveSync for the mailbox alltogether? `Set-CasMailbox -Identity "the.user@yourcompany.com" -ActiveSyncEnabled $false`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem - you need to use Get-ADObject to find the empty nodes, and then pipe to Remove-ADObject to remove them. Sorry I don't have a script to share as I used Excel and some powershell commands to:

- see if the node exists
- check it's empty
- remove the node

This is just to confirm that Remove-MobileDevice doesn't delete the empty offending node that affected my ADMT migration.